# Easier way to convert a character to an integer?

Tags: julia

Still getting a feel for what's in the Julia standard library. I can convert strings to their integer representation via the `Int()` constructor, but when I call `Int()` with a `Char` I don't integer value of a digit:

```
julia> Int('3')
51
```

Currently I'm calling `string()` first:

```
intval = Int(string(c)) # doesn't work anymore, see note below
```

Is this the accepted way of doing this? Or is there a more standard method? It's coming up quite a bit in my Project Euler exercise.

---

**Note:** This question was originally asked before Julia 1.0. Since it was asked the `int` function was renamed to `Int` and became a method of the `Int` type object. The method `Int(::String)` for parsing a string to an integer was removed because of the potentially confusing difference in behavior between that and `Int(::Char)` discussed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer is you can do `parse(Int, c)` to do this correctly and efficiently. Read on for more discussion and details.

The code in the question as originally asked doesn't work anymore because `Int(::String)` was removed from the languge because of the confusing difference in behavior between it and `Int(::Char)`. Prior to Julia 1.0, the former was parsing a string as an integer whereas the latter was giving the unicode code point of the character which meant that `Int("3")` would return 3 whereaas `Int('3')` would return 51. The modern working equivalent of what the questioner was using would be `parse(Int, string(c))`. However, you can skip converting the character to a string (which is quite inefficient) and just write `parse(Int, c)`.

What does `Int(::Char)` do and why does `Int('3')` return 51? That is the code point value assigned to the character `3` by the Unicode Consortium, which was also the ASCII code point for it before that. Obviously, this is not the same as the digit value of the letter. It would be nice if these matched, but they don't. The code points 0-9 are a bunch of non-printing "control characters" starting with the NUL byte that terminates C strings. The code points for decimal digits are at least contiguous, however:

```
julia> [Int(c) for c in "0123456789"]
10-element Vector{Int64}:
 48
 49
 50
 51
 52
 53
 54
 55
 56
 57
```

Because of this you can compute the value of a digit by subtracting the code point of `0` from it:

```
julia> [Int(c) - Int('0') for c in "0123456789"]
10-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
```

Since subtraction of `Char` values works and subtracts their code points, this can be simplified to `[c-'0' for c in "0123456789"]`. Why not do it this way? You can! That is exactly what you'd do in C code. If you know your code will only ever encounter `c` values that are decimal digits, then this works well. It doesn't, however, do any error checking whereas `parse` does:

```
julia> c = 'f'
'f': ASCII/Unicode U+0066 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)

julia> parse(Int, c)
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit 'f'
Stacktrace:
 [1] parse(::Type{Int64}, c::Char; base::Int64)
   @ Base ./parse.jl:46
 [2] parse(::Type{Int64}, c::Char)
   @ Base ./parse.jl:41
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[38]:1

julia> c - '0'
54
```

Moreover, `parse` is a bit more flexible. Suppose you want to accept `f` as a hex "digit" encoding the value 15. To do that with `parse` you just need to use the `base` keyword argument:

```
julia> parse(Int, 'f', base=16)
15

julia> parse(Int, 'F', base=16)
15
```

As you can see it parses upper or lower case hex digits correctly. In order to do that with the subtraction method, your code would need to do something like this:

```
'0' <= c <= '9' ? c - '0' :
'A' <= c <= 'F' ? c - 'A' + 10 :
'a' <= c <= 'f' ? c - 'a' + 10 : error()
```

Which is actually quite close to the implementation of the `parse(Int, c)` method. Of course at that point it's much clearer and easier to just call `parse(Int, c)` which does this for you and is well optimized.

Comment: `parseint(s)` is deprecated. Use `parse(Int, s)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It was not yet deprecated when I answered this.

Comment: `Int(c)` seems to be the method that works as of more recent Julia versions

Comment: @Alec, I think Int(c) returns the Unicode code point of the character, not the corresponding integer. For example Int('\pi<tab>') returns 960.